# How to check if a number has a decimal place/is a whole number?

Tags: java, java-8, floating-point, decimal

My input field [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html) **num** may contain both integer and floating numbers.

```
num = 45
or 
num = 45.5343434
```

If the `BigDecimal` input field `num` contains decimal places, then I would like to limit the decimal places to 4.

```
Desired Output : 45.5343 if input num = 45.5343434
Desired Output : 45 if input num=45
```

How can I do that?

Comment: What exactly is the data type of `num` in your example?

Comment: I assume your input field yields a String containing the number? Then you could use `Double d = Double.parseDouble(String)` to convert the String to a Double. Afterwards remove unwanted decimal places by `d = Math.round(d * 10000) / 10000.0`

Comment: What is your question? Check if a number is a decimal/whole number or restrict the amount of trailing numbers after the decimal point?

Comment: @BasilBourque My input field is BigDecimal.

Comment: @Spectric Yes. your assumption is correct.  Expected Behavior: Check if a number is a decimal/whole number or restrict the amount of trailing numbers after the decimal point?

Comment: @user15350142 Do you have to use BigDecimal?

Comment: What  exactly do you mean by “output”?

Comment: @Spectric Yes please. i need to use BigDecimal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are interested in what is called the *scale* of your `BigDecimal`.

Call [`BigDecimal#scale`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html#scale()).

```java
BigDecimal x = new BigDecimal( "45.5343434" );
BigDecimal y = new BigDecimal( "45" );
```

> x.scale(): 7
>
> y.scale(): 0

You asked:

> I would like to limit the decimal places by 4

Test for the scale being larger than four. If so, [round](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding).

```
    BigDecimal num = new BigDecimal(45);
    if (num.scale() > 4) {
        num = num.setScale(4, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    }
    System.out.println(num);
```

Output:

> 45

In case of more decimals:

```
    BigDecimal num = new BigDecimal("45.5343434");
```

> 45.5343

You can choose a different rounding mode to fit with your requirements.